# ActionView::TemplateError (integer 23656121084180 too big to convert to `unsigned int')

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the weirdest error I've ever got on Rails. Any idea what this may be is?

NOTE: the error DOES NOT come from @order.get_invoice_number, I've tried to separate the code into multiple lines and it was clear the problem is within {:host... }

```
    ActionView::TemplateError (integer 23656121084180 too big to convert to `unsigned int') on line #56 of app/views/order_mailer/order_detail.text.html.erb:
    53:                 <b>Order #:</b>
    54:               </td>
    55:               <td width="98%">
    56:                   <%= link_to "#{@order.get_invoice_number}", {:host => Thread.current[:host], :controller => 'store/account', :action => 'view_order', id => "#{@order.id}"}, {:target => '_blank'} %>
    57:               </td>
    58:             </tr>
    59:             <tr>

        app/views/order_mailer/order_detail.text.html.erb:56
        app/controllers/store/

test_controller.rb:11:in `order_email'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anything, it proves programmers work need healthier sleep routine.

Problem was in id => "#{@order.id} should be :id =>...